# Get desired output using mongoDB find

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have following documents in my collection

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5166fefbc482c31052000002"),
contact: [
    {
        home: 7735734105
    },
    {
        office: 9583866301
    }
],
user_name: "moti",
reportsTo: "bikram",
technology: [
    {
        name: ".net",
        rating: 5
    },
    {
        name: "JavaScript",
        rating: 2
    }
],
project: [
    "Agile School",
    "Draftmate"
],
type: "developer",
email: "motiranjan.pradhan@ajatus.co.in"
```

}
and

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5166fe90c482c31052000001"),
contact: [
    {
        home: 7735734103
    },
    {
        office: 9583866901
    }
],
user_name: "ganesh",
reportsTo: "bikram",
technology: [
    {
        name: "JavaScript",
        rating: 3
    },
    {
        name: ".net",
        rating: 4
    }
],
project: [
    "SLBC",
    "Draftmate"
],
type: "developer",
email: "ganesh.patra@ajatus.co.in"
```

}

Now I need to find the rating of the people who know only JavaScript.Currently if I run

`db.users.find(
   {
      technology: {
                $elemMatch: {
                     name: 'JavaScript'
                }
      }
   },{user_name:1,'technology.name':1,_id:0}
 ).pretty()`

I am getting names of all technologies(.net & JavaScript) and their corresponding ratings. I need only user names,and their respective ratings in JavaScript only. Do I need to use any aggregation techniques?

Comment: Try running the following: db.users.find( { technology: { $elemMatch: { name: 'JavaScript' } } },{user_name:1,'technology.$.name':1,_id:0} )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [positional operator '$'](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/#prj._S_) can be used to limit query results to the first matching element. To use in your query above you would change it to:

```
db.users.find( { technology: { $elemMatch: { name: 'JavaScript' } } },{user_name:1,'technology.$.name':1,_id:0} )
```

Comment: thanks james. Just one more query. How do I display the output as "Ganesh has a JavaScript rating of 3" ?

Comment: var result = db.users.findOne( { technology: { $elemMatch: { name: 'JavaScript' } } },{user_name:1,'technology.$.name':1,_id:0} )

Comment: print(result.user_name + " has a "+ result.technology[0].name + " rating of " + result.technology[0].rating)